# Blender Internal glossy BSDF equivalent?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

O.k. I'm back and now i need to know how to make a metallic material in Blender Internal.
The last question was for cycles and that fixed my problem, but Blender Internal doesn't have a Glossy BSDF. How do I get a glossy/metallic material in BI?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a tutorial request. A quick search on YouTube would bring up a multitude of tutorials.

Comment: What do you mean OFF TOPIC?

Comment: Blender Internal does have glossy reflections: www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-246/glossy-reflectionrefraction

Comment: @OwenPatterson, please read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd like to add some information about the settings on top of [micgdev's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1464/12):

*Reflectivity*: There you define how strong the reflection is. 1 is fully reflective, 0 means no reflection at all. A fully reflective surface is non-existant, even a mirror is around 0.9..

*Fresnel*: Do you know the effect when you're looking at car windows from different angles? One time (when you face them) it's almost transparent, the other time it's almost a mirror (looking at them from the side). This effect is the fresnel effect and you enable it with this slider.

*Glossy*: With a glossy "amount" value below 1 you're setting the glossiness. 1 means very glossy, all below 1 means that the reflection will be blurred out.

*Anisotropic*: With this slider you can alter the reflection kind. If you're turning it up, the reflection will behave more and more like under a pot (become more and more circular).

I think that should set you up for the first steps...but read the documentation and experiment - there is so much to test and find out :)

Answer (score 6):

Enable Mirror, it's in your material settings. See the Blender wiki article on [materials](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual#Materials) for more. Specifically the section on [mirrors](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Properties/Mirror) will be of interest, there you will find a run-down of what each parameter does.

[image: Mirror settings for Blender Internal]

Comment: @micgdev I added a screenshot and a link to the wiki, we try to make Blender SE a thick web of information.