# How do I apply an environment map in Blender Internal?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm using Blender Internal due to its object outline effect, and am trying to use a 1800 degree environment map for the reflections (not lighting). I'm trying what seems like should work, and am failing.

Most of the tutorials for this are in Cycles, which is handled easily, can anyone tell me how to do it in Blender 2.6+ Internal?

EDITS:

So my question is really just "How do I apply an environment map in Blender Internal?"; the perspective of the environment map is trivial to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "1800 degree environment map".. Do you mean 180 degree? Or am missing something?

Comment: @gandalf3 It's 1800. Look into the options of panorama rendering. It's not based on a 180 or 360(we think 360, but that's just a circle, 1800 is an orb) perspective view of the scene, but a 1800 degree view, which is basically a full sphere view mapped onto one image. The environment map takes that warped image and turns it into a 360 environment map emulating the actual environment for lighting and/or reflections.

Comment: For example in this short tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQ1rV-xOhWY if he had a cloud overhead, it wouldn't show up in the environment map because that's a 360 degree panoramic.

Comment: It might be possible in BI, I don't know. However, one option is to render the sky in cycles in a different scene and composite together.

Comment: Can you give an example of a failed attempt? Can you give an example of a 1800 degree environment map?

Comment: @Gunslinger Yes, I'll provide a 180 degree and 1800 degree version of the same environment mapped. My failed attempt is due to me not figuring out how to assign the environment map to my environment. In cycles, it's easy. A tutorial also shows it easily being done in blender internal, but that was an older interface and the way to do it must be different now. I'll post the maps in a moment.

Comment: The way the map is assigned to the environment doesn't have to do with the perspective of the map by the way. They'll both be applied the same. It's the way that the maps bend above and below that changes. It's like texturing the sphere with an environment, but blender does it for you.

Comment: So my question is really just "How do I apply an environment map in Blender Internal?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Enable *Real Sky* in *Properties > World* to make the sky render relative to the horizon rather than the camera:

   [image]

   Optionally enable *Environment lighting* to use the sky texture to illuminate the scene.
2. Switch to the texture panel and create a new *world texture* by clicking *new* with the *World* tab selected:

   [image]
3. Set the type to *Image or Movie* and open an image:

   [image]
4. In *Textures > Mapping* set the projection to *Equirectangular* and enable *Horizon* in *Textures > Influence*:

   [image]

### Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to use Blender Render.
How did you get a fully reflective Material here?
Thanks!

Comment: @CFS See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1451/599